# To find the domain of a function

Tags: functions

How to find the domain of the function $ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\tan x| -\tan(x)}}? $

**My attempt:**
since the expression under the root should be greater than zero so $\vert \tan x \vert - \tan x > 0 $ and $\vert \tan x \vert > \tan x $ but I'm stuck here so please help.
I thought of taking $x<0$ and $x>0$ but then I'm not able to bring out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dividing according to the sign of $x$, give $\tan x$ a name such as $y$, and ask yourself:

For which $y$ do we have $|y|>y$?

Comment: So if I put tanx=y and compare |y|>y then I get y>0 for |y|=(-y) , so tanx>0 , is this the way it should be done?Please check.

Comment: @Kanchi: Yes, that's what I would do.

Comment: So I should check for the domain where tanx is >0 in the tanx graph. Ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given the function $f : D_f \to \mathbb{R}$ of law:
$$f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\tan x| - \tan x}}\,,$$
its natural domain is thus determinable:
$$
|\tan x| > \tan x 
\; \; \; \; \; \; \Leftrightarrow \; \; \; \; \; \;
\begin{cases}
\tan x < 0 \\
- \tan x > \tan x
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \cup \; \; \;
\begin{cases}
\tan x \ge 0 \\
\tan x > \tan x
\end{cases}\,.
$$
To conclude you.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{x}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\notin \mathbb{Z}$$ and $$-\frac{\pi}{2}<x-2\pi n<0$$
or
$$\frac{x}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\notin \mathbb{Z}$$ and $$\frac{\pi}{2}<x-2\pi n<\pi$$
wher5e $n$ is an integer.

Comment: This helped me after I checked graph of tanx.Thanks.